# How can i recieve edited/updated data from another screen to the main screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Currently i am learning flutter and i am stucked in navigation. what i wanted to achieve is : 
A Variable which is global to all the screens :
   For Example There is a variable score on the main page which is initialize with zero and on main page there are four buttons which takes to four different screen and after clicking a button on main page  the screen changes to another. Now in another screen we will perform something which updates the value of score.Now when we come back to main page the updated score should be reflected and also if we click on some other button which takes us to another screen,updated score should also be reflected there.

Comment: Please share your code, so that we can help you. It would be good if you followed the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am not able to do it sir ,thats why i ask the question but what i am asking is how a single variable can updated in different screen and can be reflected to other screens also. I hope you understand sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in more than one way, but the simplest is using the Navigator class and passing the value you want to pass back to the parent widget through the `.pop()` method to return to your first view, like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(your_data_here);
```

On the parent class, where you used your Navigator to navigate to the other view, you can expect to receive the data:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return OtherView();
      }
    )).then((value_from_other_view){
      // You can here use the data from the other view
    });
  },
)
```

Comment: The answer provided by João Soares should be able to solve your problem. Just a tip however, that if you are planning to use flutter in the long run, and in medium to large scale projects in the future; you should learn state management via Provider, Bloc, or other state management packages. Trust me; they're worth it. Makes everything easier and much more maintanable. Just a tip ;)

Comment: Definitely support what Rick said above. Once you get more comfortable with Flutter in the future, look into state management. I personally prefer ScopedModel.

Comment: Sirs you are don't understanding what I am telling. What I wanted to achieve is if I update the value of variable in one screen it should be automatically updates in all the other screen where the variable is used